# SQLDeveloper equivalent to SQLServers "Script Table as Insert" CRUD statement templates

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

How can I ask SQLDeveloper to generate CRUD templates for a given table, and place them in a SQLWorksheet, so that I can fill in the arguments by hand and execute the DML operation requested?

The feature I'm looking for would be roughtly equivalant to the MS SQLServer SSMS "Script Table as" -> "Select | Insert | Update To" -> "Query Editor" which is available when Right clicking a Table.

Additionally if you have any tips on how to look at the definition of Two tables from the same Connection at once, I would be most appreciative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

drag and drop your table to a worksheet

[image]

This generates

```
INSERT
INTO EMPLOYEES
  (
    EMPLOYEE_ID,
    FIRST_NAME,
    LAST_NAME,
    EMAIL,
    PHONE_NUMBER,
    HIRE_DATE,
    JOB_ID,
    SALARY,
    COMMISSION_PCT,
    MANAGER_ID,
    DEPARTMENT_ID
  )
  VALUES
  (
    :v0,
    :v1,
    :v2,
    :v3,
    :v4,
    :v5,
    :v6,
    :v7,
    :v8,
    :v9,
    :v10
  );
```

If you select multiple objects and choose 'SELECT' and 'JOIN', we'll join the tables together, assuming you have a Foreign Key constraint linking them.

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: No worries. I have a lot of how-to's for folks on my blog if you get stuck with anything else.